# Converting an image to base64 URI on a angular/electron app

Tags: angular, electron, base64

So I'm building an angular/electron desktop app and i need to convert an image to a base64 URI, my image is located at `assets/logo/logo.png`and I'm making an http request to the same path to get the image as follows:

```
this.http
      .get('/assets/logo/logo.png', { responseType: 'blob' })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          var base64data = reader.result;
          this.logo = base64data;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(data);
      });
```

This works on the browser but it doesn't work when i build the electron app and i get the following error:

```
main.4a1ed7a….js:1 ERROR 
jB
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: YB {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for /assets/logo/logo.png: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "/assets/logo/logo.png"
__proto__: TB
```

Is there any other way to load the image without making an http request to the assets directory??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was trying to fix the bug and i came out with a simple solution, i was making a GET HTTP request to `assets/logo/logo.png`and it worked fine on the browser but when i build the app on electron i was receiving an error, then i wondered what if i make the request to `./assets/logo/logo.png`and it worked!! I'm not sure why does it work but i suppose is because the way that electron works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know electron and node that much, and I don't know how the `FileReader` thingy works (is node? electron? or this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader ? maybe clarify this in the question). But as its name suggests, it probably reads *files*, but you want to pass it a blob, which is not a file. Also, I suspect that the method `readAsDataURL` doesn't expect a param, it probably just reads the file that the `FileReader` is already initialised with.

An actual solution might be to use the [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) method, which can encode base64. If you encode the blob (the `data` variable in your subscribe), you might be able to create a data url with that value.

Comment: Thank you so much! Although it didn't helped me your comment gave me an idea and i know what's the issue now, the thing is that the HTTP request to `assets/logo/logo.png`works fine on browser, but when i build the electron app i get an error because it should be making the request to `./assets/logo/logo.png`. Thank you so much for stopping by!!